# Abstract Algebra: For a group K satisfying H⊂K⊂G, prove that either K=G or K=H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a (not necessarily finite) group and let $H$ be a subgroup of G with exactly two distinct cosets. For a group $K$ satisfying $H \subset K \subset G$, prove that either $K=G$ or $K=H$.

So far, I have split the proof into two cases.

i) When G is finite and ii) when G is infinite.

For i) I said that since$ |G:H| =2, H=|G|/2$.

Also, $2= |G:H| = |G|/|H| = |G|/|K| x |K|/|H| = (|G:H|) x (|K:H|)$.

I then go to consider if $|G:K|=1$ or $|K:H|=1$.

For ii) I don't know how to proceed as there are no theorems that work with an infinite group. I considered splitting ii) into further cases since an infinite group can have an infinite subgroup of finite order, a finite subgroup of infinite order, and an infinite subgroup of infinite order. However, I am struggling with this portion. 
Any help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $G$ is infinite, $|G/H|=2$. If $K$ is an intermediate subgroup, we have $2=|G/H|=|G/K||K/H|$. Since $2$ is prime, $|G/K|$ is either $1$ or $2$. If it is $1$, then $G=K$. If it's $2$, then $|K/H|=1$, so $K=H$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split into cases.

Suppose $H\ne K$. Then there exists $x\in K$, $x\notin H$.

Take $g\in G$; if $g\in H$, then $g\in K$ by assumption. If $g\notin H$, then $Hg=Hx$ because there are just two cosets, so $h=gx^{-1}\in H$, by definitions of right coset, therefore $g=hx\in K$. Hence $K=G$.

An obvious modification holds for left cosets.

Comment: So, will the proof still be valid if it is split into two cases or would using the left and right coset argument create a better proof?

Comment: @ljc_growl You gain nothing at all by splitting into the finite and infinite case.